# Yarn: How to make Yarn utilize more memory and vcores

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

we have a 5 node cluster managed by Yarn and running hadoop

1 Master name node 8 vcores and 24GB memory

4 data nodes each 8 vcores and 24GB memory

When i look at Yarn configuration on the ui as highlighted in the picture below it's only using 16GB and 6 vcores

[image]

Our application is using all of the 16gb so want to increase the memory since its available (24 - 2gb for os so avialable is 22gb)

where do i need to configure this 22gb instead of 16gb ?

From research found yarn-site.xml might be the place so went ahead and updated it and restarted yarn but still its showing 16gb

Would grealty appreciate if any of the experts in the community will help out as we are new to Yarn

this is the yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hdfs-name-node</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>21528</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>6</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>21528</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir,file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/filecache,file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/usercache</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms</name>
        <value>500</value>
    </property>

    <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb</name>
         <value>512</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0:8039</value>
    </property>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is completely wrong. According to your attached image, your total memory which is used by yarn is 64GB and VCores are 24.

Highlighted part in image is scheduler memory and vcores, which designed by your admin for a tenant.

If you are part of the scheduler queue, you can use maximum 16 GB and 6 Vcores.

Comment: Wayne  you might be right that our understanding may be wrong .......i have updated the question with our  **yarn-site.xml** please take a look at it and help us understand better ...we are not using any queues ..and this cluster is a dedicated cluster for only this job .......if we have **22gb** on each node our cluster memory capacity should have been 4*22 = **88GB** not sure why yarn is showing 4*16gb = 64GB ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the image, your cluster capacity is 64GB and 24 vcores.

The red circle(oval actually ;)) shows the resources configured for your capacity scheduler.

> where do i need to configure this 22gb instead of 16gb ?

You need to configure your queue (provided you have proper permissions to do so). For more info read [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Queue_Properties)

Comment: we are not using any queues as such this a dedicated cluster for this job ...if you think it will help to add **capacity-scheduler.xml** i will be happy to do that ..but i looked at it and there is no value we configured

Comment: The yarn has an internal queue for allocating cluster resources to jobs. You are using the default yarn queue. So I would suggest you to try adding capacity-scheduler.xml and configure `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-allocation-vcores` properties with full cluster capacity(64gb, 24vcores) as explained in the reference that I gave.